# Why I can not get the facebook connect button with facebooker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

My rails version is 2.3.4.

At first I install the gem

> gem install facebooker

and then add these code to login page

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<%= fb_connect_javascript_tag %>
<%= init_fb_connect "XFBML" %> 
<%= fb_login_and_redirect(facebook_login_users_path) %>
```

and add some code to application_controller

```
before_filter :set_facebook_session
helper_method :facebook_session
```

But I cannot see the blue connect button!

I think i miss something, who can give me some advice? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. if using jquery the code need to be:

```
<%= fb_connect_javascript_tag :js => :jquery %>
```

Comment: also <%= init_fb_connect "XFBML", :js => :jquery %>